# WiFi repeater with a fallback source?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, repeater

Let's say I have 2 broadband routers from different providers, let's call them Primary and Secondary. Can I set up a repeater in such a way that if Primary router looses power and/or internet connection the repeater would automatically switch to the Secondary router? I don't have any specific device in mind, just looking to buy one.

Comment: Do the wifi networks from both router have the same SSID? or are they in the same network?

Comment: Let's assume under ideal scenario the Primary and Secondary routers have different SSIDs, even though they could potentially have same one if need be. Is there much difference?

Comment: If both have the same SSID almost every repeater would suffice. with different SSIDs you either need specialised hard/software or you could build your own Repeater using Linux with maybe Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is to get a dual wan router and configure it to work with primary and fallback internet connections, pretty much out of the box solution.